# sql запрос "лента новостей"

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Помогите сформировать sql запрос так называемой "ленты новостей" тоесть выводить только записи своих друзей.

таблица друзей frends - id | user | frend
таблица новостей lenta - id | user | text | time

```
frends     id | user | frend
        1    nik   nik2   
        2    nik   nik3   
        3    nik3  nik2
        4    nik4  nik2

lenta      id |  user | text | time
        1    nik3   text1
        2    nik2   text2 
        3    nik4   text3
        4    nik2   text4
        5    nik4   text5 
        6    nik3   text6
```

нужно что бы выводились записи только пользователей nik2 и nik3, так как они мои друзья. Вроде этого - text1, text2, text4, text6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select `text`
from lenta
where `user` in (select friend from friends where `user` = 'nik')
```

Comment: пока тестирую, но вроде то что нужно.

Comment: всё заработало когда поменял frend и user местами. ещё вопрос, есть ещё таблица с подписчиками нужно что бы если пользователь подписан то так же выводило, всё сделал так. Можно так?

Comment: select text from lenta where user in (select frend from frends where user = 'nik') UNION ALL select text from lenta where user in (select frend from new_frends where user = 'nik')

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `lenta`.`text` 
FROM `lenta`
JOIN `frends`
ON `lenta`.`user` = `frends`.`frend`;
```

Добавил "DISTINCT", исключающий повторы строк в выборке.

Comment: @Den  я подправил свой код, теперь работает. Как я и говорил - или левый, или правый join надо юзать. Левый не сработал, значит по логике нужно брать правый (RIGHT можно не указывать). Результат выборки : text1 text2 text4 text6

Comment: Вам необходимо срочно ознакомиться с тем, какие виды JOIN бывают, вы несёте ядерную пургу сейчас :)

Answer (score 0):

Для небольших таблиц отлично будут работать варианты, которые представлены выше, но обычно такие таблицы редко остаются небольшими. При сколько-нибудь большом количестве данных база данных с такой архитектурой ляжет. Поэтому вот мой совет:

1. Переведите поля user и friend в целочисленные (INT). Так поиск будет происходить намного быстрее. Выставите простой индекс на поле user в первой таблице и и составной (user, time) на второй.
2. Лучше не использовать запросы с джоинами, если предполагаете большой объем данных, связанность данных не позволит хорошо масштабировать систему. Что касается самого запроса, то его лучше разбить на 2 (в первом мы просто узнает весь список friend_id пользователя, а во втором вставляем в условие WHERE этот список).

Почему именно такой совет, а не через JOIN? Допустим, у Вас 10 тыс. активных пользователей, у каждого условно по 100 друзей, итого 1 млн. записей в первой таблице. Без перевода в INT она уже будет тормозить или вообще ляжет. Далее вторая таблица, допустим раз в неделю каждый активный пользователь публикует 2-3 записи, итого за год будет 1-1.5 млн. записей, по каждой из которых надо проводить проверку. Уже на таком объеме указанные выше запросы работать не будут. И это ни разу даже близко не High Load.

Comment: Хорошо когда соображаешь в mysql мне пока очень тяжело составлять такие sql запросы, в основном движок пишется на простых запросах, единственное остановило меня это новостная лента. Достаточно подробно всё обьяснили, но пока мне это не по зубам. Такой запрос сейчас у меня, если можете оптимизируйте этот запрос с готовым примером, буду очень благодарен.  select text from lenta where user in (select user from frends where frend = 'nik') UNION ALL select text from lenta where user in (select user from new_frends where frend = 'nik') ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: lenta - новости frends - друзья new_frends - подписчики, в принципе она такая же как и frends

Comment: 1. во-первых надо немного поменять саму структуру базы данных, перевести часть полей в INT как я говорил выше. далее делаем запрос на поиск друзей пользователя: select friend_id from friends where user_id = 'user_id'.

Comment: 2. по найденным friend_id формируем второй запрос: SELECT text FROM lenta WHERE user_id='friend_id_1' OR user_id='friend_id_2' OR ...  ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 20. в этом запросе LIMIT определяет количество выводимых записей за раз, а первое число (в данном случае 0 - OFFSET (отступ)

Comment: конечно, второй запрос в моем примере более простой, чем должен быть. правильнее так SELECT text FROM lenta USE INDEX (user_id, time) WHERE time<'time_offset' AND (user_id='friend_id_1' OR user_id='friend_id_2' OR ...) ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 20. но на первое время вполне сойдет и ранее указанный вариант. также, если сложно сразу все переварить, можете использовать и те запросы, которые были указаны в других ответах (технически там все верно). но имейте ввиду, что все равно придется переходить к более сложной схеме. таблицы ленты новостей маленькими не бывают.

Comment: @Den и еще совет, поработайте над namespace (названия таблиц, колонок и т.д.). лучше его привести в порядок до старта проекта, потом править куда сложнее. но это опять совет на будущее, когда число разработчиков становится более чем 1))

Comment: спасибо большое, буду разбираться

Comment: *Лучше не использовать запросы с джоинами, если предполагаете большой объем данных* -- в общем случае чушь, сильно зависит от того, что может оптимизатор. Хороший оптимизатор из эквивалентных запросов через подзапрос и через джоин сгенерирует одинаковые планы выполнения, а если нет, то надо не вслепую предпочитать одно другому, а измерять, что быстрее -- и очень часто джоин быстрее, т. к. требует меньше хитростей со стороны оптимизатора. А совет перевести ключи на инты дельный, да.